# NativeSearchQueryBuilder match special fields

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to create a NativeSearchQuery which searches through all fields we mapped, the _all tag is all I need, however building it in code does not work the way I'd like it:

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(indexName)
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", request.getSearchTerm().getSearchString()))
        .withPageable(new PageRequest(request.getPaging(), request.getMaxResults()))
        .build();
```

creates a query which looks like this:

```
{
  "match" : {
    "_all" : {
      "query" : "<searchterm>",
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

but to fulfill my intention, it has to look like that:

```
{
  "match" : {
    _all : {
      "query" : "<searchterm>",
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried match all query ?